# salesforce not expected object returned calling query

Tags: php, salesforce

I am using the sforce-php toolkit to get some objects from salesforce. I have the following code:

```
$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/partner.wsdl.xml');
$mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
$query = "SELECT FirstName from Contact";
$response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
$queryResult = new QueryResult($response);

foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {
    print_r($record);
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

and i expect the objects returned in this form:

```
stdClass Object
(
[type] = Contact
[Id] = Array
    (
        [0] =&gt; 003i0000009GZVzAAO
        [1] =&gt; 003i0000009GZVzAAO
    )
[FirstName] = "Some String" 
[any] = <sf:firstname>Some String</sf:firstname>
)
```

so i can get the FirstName of the object like
$record->FirstName

but what i get is:

```
stdClass Object
(
[type] = Contact
[Id] = Array
    (
        [0] =&gt; 003i0000009GZVzAAO
        [1] =&gt; 003i0000009GZVzAAO
    )
[any] = <sf:firstname>Some String</sf:firstname>
)
```

so i cannot get the FirstName. The only attribute i have access is 'any'. How can i get an object as the expected one? Where should i focus?

Comment: Is this not a PHP data question, where you just happen to be using salesforce? Can't you just parse the [any] and get your data - it is there after all.

Comment: Have you used Partner or Enterprise WSDL? Looks Partner to me (generic but you don't get strongly typed fields = you don't get explicit nodes in XML, you need to parse "any"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your account has permission to access FirstName custom-field via webservice call.